# Set the client width without changing the screen itself

Tags: javascript

I have an admin panel. There's a column on the side. I want to change the client width to 100% - 480px. (sidebar width). How stupid is this decision? ;) I need to show the content in adaptive mode.

Comment: This would be better done in CSS. You could do it in JS/jQuery too if you like.

Comment: What's client width?

Comment: @Twisty Can you tell me how? It's hard to do in css because you have to pull a lot of code out inline. To prescribe a condition if admin == true.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ document.clientWidth

Comment: @8X3ETcA7fqD then I would just add a class with JS and let CSS handle the styling of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two examples:

```js
function changeSize(id, col) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (el) {
    el.style.width = (document.body.clientWidth - col) + "px";
  }
}

changeSize("new", 480);
```

```css
.page {
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.panel {
  width: calc(100% - 480px);
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #fff;
}

#new {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="panel">
    Panel 1
  </div>
  <br />
  <div id="new">
    Panel 2
  </div>
</div>
```

See More:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: tnx you! its work